# How can I search any volume in macOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, search

```
 - (void)readFolder:(NSString *)str :(NSMutableDictionary *)dict {
    NSArray *appFolderContents = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    appFolderContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:str error:nil];
    for (NSString *app in appFolderContents) {
        if ([app containsString:@".app"])
        {
            NSString *appName = [[app lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
            NSString *appPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", str, app];
            NSString *appBundle = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:appPath] bundleIdentifier];
//            NSLog(@"%@ -- %@", appPath, appBundle);
            NSArray *jumboTron = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:appName, appPath, appBundle, nil];
            [dict setObject:jumboTron forKey:appName];
        }
    }
}

//This searches for apps
- (void)getAPPList {
    NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [self readFolder:@"/Applications" :myDict];
    [self readFolder:@"/Applications/Utilities" :myDict];
    [self readFolder:@"/System/Library/CoreServices" :myDict];
    [self readFolder:@"/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications" :myDict ];

// Volumes not named 'Macintosh HD' doesn't work, I'm trying to make it work
    [self readFolder:@"/Volumes/*/Applications" :myDict ];
//Some apps are stored in the user's Application folder instead of the main one
    [self readFolder:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Applications", NSHomeDirectory()] :myDict];
//Sometimes people keep apps in Downloads
    [self readFolder:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Downloads", NSHomeDirectory()] :myDict];
//Some apps are stored in the user's Library/Application Support sometimes
    [self readFolder:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Application Support", NSHomeDirectory()] :myDict];
```

I'm trying to make line 26 (`[self readFolder:@"/Volumes/*/Applications" :myDict ]`) search all volumes, instead of only searching a volume with a matching/specific name. How can I do this?

I'm using Xcode 9.2

Comment: Did you try a single call to `readFolder` with a path of `@"/"` ?

Comment: @rmaddy yes, it appears to only show successfully search when given the closest directory. If it would help, here is the github project: https://github.com/The-SamminAter/DarkMode

Comment: You need to perform a recursive search.

Comment: @rmaddy how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should do the trick (untested)

```
   NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLVolumeURLKey, NSURLIsVolumeKey, nil];
   NSArray *volumeUrls = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:keys options:NSVolumeEnumerationSkipHiddenVolumes];
  for (NSURL *volumeUrl in volumeUrls)
  {
     BOOL mayBeBootVolume = NO;
     NSString* pathToVolume = [volumeUrl path];
     [self readFolder: [pathToVolume stringByAppendingString: @"/Applications"];
  }
```

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if I'm doing this right (because I'm not very good at this), but wherever I put this it gives me errors. Is there a specific place where this should go?